# Open image in browser with Ruby

Tags: ruby

Learning Ruby, early stages. I have a very simple script that I run on terminal and I want it to open files in browser based on user input. What code can I use (I have found references to RoR so far, didn't help):

```
puts "What type of train would u like to see today? steam or diesel"
print "> "
train = $stdin.gets.chomp
if train == "steam"
```

> what code can I put so script opens xyz image on browser?

```
elsif train == "diesel"
```

> what code can I put so script opens xyz image on browser?

```
else "Sorry, I didn't understand that. Bye"

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use something like Selenium Webdriver to launch and control the browser window. You will need to install the selenium-webdriver gem, and in this example I'm using Chrome (which requires chromedriver also), so you'll need to have that installed as well (you can use `:firefox` instead if you'd like).

Try this:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
puts "What type of train would u like to see today? steam or diesel"

train = gets.chomp

if train == "steam"
  driver.get 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_locomotive'
elsif train == "diesel"
  driver.get 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_locomotive'
else "Sorry, I didn't understand that. Bye"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Open

The easiest way to open a web browser from the command line is to use the [open command](https://ss64.com/bash/open.html). If given a string that looks like a URL (starts with http, has a TLD, etc), the open command is smart enough to launch the current default web browser.

## Backticks and %x

Luckily, Ruby's Kernel module (which all objects inherit) includes a [method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60) to quickly launch a subshell, perform some work, and then return execution to your ruby script.

We can either accomplish this with backticks:

`` `open https://google.com` ``

Or with the %x syntax, which lets us define our own delimiters (personally, I prefer this style):

`%x(open https://google.com)`

The above code should open a new browser tab in your default browser and point it to google. As a side note, I've noticed that if you have multiple browser windows open, it seems arbitrary which window the new tab is opened in, so if you don't see the browser pop up, check your minimized windows.

It's worth mentioning that when shell commands in the subshell would write to stdout, output is instead returned to your script as a string. This is great because we can do stuff like this:

`files_in_home_directory = %x(cd && ls -a)`

You can also use string interpolation!

```
song = "https://open.spotify.com/track/5ghIJDpPoe3CfHMGu71E6T"
%x(open #{song})
```

## Process.spawn

The above method is blocking, meaning that your ruby script grinds to a halt and waits for the subshell to finish its work before returning control to your script. This is totally fine for doing small things like opening a link in a browser, however if you ever need to do something slower in that subshell, you're gonna have a bad time. `Process.spawn` lets us open a subshell in another process and then forget about it. Either its work gets done or it doesn't, but our ruby script can go about its business:

`%x(sleep 10 && open https://google.com)` will pause not only the subshell but also your script

`Process.spawn("sleep 10 && open https://google.com")` will allow your script to continue while the subshell does its job in another process.

Unlike the backticks/%x method, Process.spawn does not return stdout as a string, instead it returns a process id. There are [many ways](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Process.html#method-c-spawn) to verify the outcome of that process using the pid.

**Warning: You should never execute a string that includes values input by the user, this is just asking for trouble.**